# Django haystack LocationField saved as string

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using Django 1.8.5, haystack 2.4.1 and elasticsearch 1.7. This question might be possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105693/django-haystack-order-by-distance-by-elasticsearch-backend-not-a-geo-point-fiel), but the problem there was because of fundamental changes in elasticsearch 2 about mappings but here the root of the problem is completely different and so I created a new question.

I want to add geo-based search to my models. To this aim, these are the changes I made:

in my searchable model:

```
latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
  longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
  def get_location(self):
            return Point(self.latitude or 1000, self.longitude or 1000)
```

in search_indexes.py:

```
location = indexes.LocationField(model_attr='get_location')
```

And by running `./manage.py build_index` we expect the mapping to be updated. I checked the mapping but surprisingly location field was saved as `string` instead of `geo_point`. Consequently, I had issues with `dwithin` filter and couldn't get the job done.

I know that I can create the mapping manually by querying elastic directly, but I want haystack to do it through `search_indexes.py`. Thus, is there any fix for haystack to fix this issue? I need to get it done ASAP.